# Como recuperar eventos en Fullcalendar con un javascript de una sql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar

de ante mano gracias, necesitaría saber como puedo llegar a inyectar eventos a FullCalendar que están guardados en una tabla MySQL, todo lo que he encontrado es desde PHP y me gustaría saber si lo puedo hacer desde JavaScript.
Gracias.

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var fecha = new Date();

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    locale: 'es',
    initialDate: fecha,
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    events: [
          /*deberia de crear tantos eventos como reguistros de la tabla de la bbdd, y los datos interlos deberian completarse con atributos de la tabla*/

          {
            title: 'My Event',/*esto deberia de cogerlo de la base de datos*/
            start: '2021-10-05',
            url: './index.php?acc=historial_libhgt'
        }
        // other events here
    ],
    eventClick: function(info) {
        info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let the browser navigate

        if (info.event.url) {
            window.open(info.event.url);
        }
    }
});

calendar.render();
```

});`

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia la prodiedad `events` por `eventSources`

y ahi debes enviar el siguiente arreglo

```html
eventSources: [{
           url: 'request/obtener_citas.php'
       }],
```

En el archivo `request/obtener_citas.php`debes obtener todas la citas de la base de datos y en un array  imprimirlo como json

Ejemplo

```html
//obtenemos las citas desde la base de datos - en este ejemplo el metodo esta en una clase  llamada citas 
$_citas = new Citas;
$listaCitas = $_citas->listaCitasEspeciales();

//Definimos un array vacio en el cual iremos agregando todas las citas ya editadas con el formato que necesita full calendar 

$mostrar = array();
foreach ($listacitas as $key => $value) {
    //Full calendar requiere un formato de fecha especial (ISO-standard) 
    $fechainicio =  $value['Fecha'] . "T" . $value['Inicio'];  
    $fechafin = $value['Fecha'] . "T" .$value['Fin'];

    //esta es una variable propia no es necesaria  pero indica el estado de la cita en este caso
    $estado = $value['Estado'];
    
    //color de la cita en codigo HEXADECIMAL
    $color = $value['Color'];

    $nuevo = array(
        'id'=> $value['CitaId'],
        'title'=> $value["Nombre"] . " - " . $value['Sala'] . " - " . $value['Servicio'],
        'start'=> $fechainicio ,
        'end' => $fechafin,
        'color' => $color,
        'estado' => $estado
    );

    $mostrar[] = $nuevo;
}

//imprimimos las citas
$print = json_encode($mostrar);
echo $print;
```

Comment: dentro de la array, como seria mas o menos la estructura? Seria algo: [{id:variable_id,inicio:variable_inicio,...},{},....] tambien, deberia de hacer un if para saber el numero de eventos, verdad?

Comment: efectivamente igual a la que tienes en el código actual

Comment: te importaría ponerme un ejemplo, la verdad que llevo desde ayer intentándolo y me sale error todo el rato, te pongo un ejemplo de lo que he hecho y mi error

Comment: He modificado la respuesta con  un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

esta seria el index(aunque en mi caso no lo es, es una paguina distinta

```
     <html>

<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link id="logonsgs" rel='icon' type="image/ico" 
        href='web/img/produccion.ico' />
    <!-- CSS   -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/material-icons.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/material.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/materialize.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="librerias/fullcalendar/main.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/dataTables.material.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 1100px;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/css/jquery-confirm.css" />
    <!--  Scripts-->
    <script src="web/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/dataTables.material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/jsPDF/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/fullcalendar/main.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/fullcalendar/locales-all.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="librerias/fullcalendar/locales/es.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

y este seria el que llama el index para rellenar:

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'produccion';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$port = "3306";
$charset = 'utf-8';
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";


try {
     $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT PID, INICIO, FIN FROM calendario ORDER BY PID;";
print_r(":: ".$query);
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'title'   => $row["PID"],
  'start'   => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row["INICIO"])),
  'end'   =>date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $row["FIN"]))
 );
};

print_r(":: ".$result);
?>
```

el que me aparece es este:

```
        index.php?acc=calendario:73 [Violation]'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 
 289ms
[Violation]Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 46ms
main.js:6476 GET http://localhost/xampp/App- 
produccion/App%20produccion%202.8/calendario/cargarevento.php?start=2021-09- 
26T00%3A00%3A00%2B02%3A00&end=2021-11-07T00%3A00%3A00%2B01%3A00 404 (Not Found)
requestJson @ main.js:6476
fetch @ main.js:6517
fetchSource @ main.js:6105
fetchSourcesByIds @ main.js:6093
fetchDirtySources @ main.js:6076
addSources @ main.js:6068
initEventSources @ main.js:6019
CalendarDataManager @ main.js:6941
Calendar @ main.js:9635
(anónimo) @ index.php?acc=calendario:77
main.js:6126 Request failed {message: 'Request failed', xhr: XMLHttpRequest}
(anónimo) @ main.js:6126
(anónimo) @ main.js:6520
xhr.onload @ main.js:6470
load (asincrónica)
requestJson @ main.js:6451
fetch @ main.js:6517
fetchSource @ main.js:6105
fetchSourcesByIds @ main.js:6093
fetchDirtySources @ main.js:6076
addSources @ main.js:6068
initEventSources @ main.js:6019
CalendarDataManager @ main.js:6941
Calendar @ main.js:9635
(anónimo) @ index.php?acc=calendario:77
```